# How did Helen Keller understand English?

Tags: 19th-century, language

Helen Keller has fascinated me for quite some time. What she achieved in her life time, being both blind and deaf.

One question though, how did she begin to comprehend the English language being both blind and deaf?

Comment: Good question. If there isn't a historical answer, you can also ask the Cognitive Sciences stack exchange for the meat.

Comment: Patty Duke knows both sides of that story.

Comment: Seriously, what aspect of this question is not immediately answered by reading the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The question isn't as trivial as it might appear; as keep in mind that sign language isn't English. The Wikipedia article is light on specifically _how_ this occurred; especially as 2 year old infant didn't have a fully established oral language to bootstrap from. And Braille, for instance, is a dreadful language to learn a priori; intended primarily for those whose eyesight is lost in latter life.

Comment: She learnt it by by feeling people's mouths as they speak, or "lip reading" via touch if you will.

Comment: @Semaphore Wrong, she did not learn how to understand English by lip reading. That's how she learned how to speak. And also, please stop editing my questions and deleting tags. I'm almost certain that this belongs in both tags of United-States and 20th-century.

Comment: It taught her what the words sounded like which is a form of "understand English". If you are asking about something else, you did not make it clear. Sullivan's work with Keller is noted in Wikipedia, you should at least explain why it didn't answer your question. And this question has absolutely nothing to do with United States or 20th century history.

Comment: @Semaphore And why not? This took place both in United States and during the 20th century.

Comment: Because it is not a question **on** the history of the United States or history of the 20th century.

Comment: @Semaphore and why not? How is this not a question of the history of the United States or 20th century? This is honestly dependent on the person, and you can interpret as you wish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17979/discussion-between-chantola-and-semaphore).

Comment: If I had the reputation, I would vote-to-close this as it is completely answered via the wiki. She had a self-made language, from which she progressed to standard sign language, taught to her in English by Anne Sullivan. She then learned to 'read lips' and finally braille. Do you doubt what the wiki tells us? Also, I agree with Semaphore. in that this question is not about the 19th century. As in it is not about a time, or time-period in that century, but about the history of a single person who happened to live then. If this were about Napoleon, an 18th century tag would also be inappropriate